# When should we begin culling tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We currently have [210 questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions) and, by my count, [129 tags](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags), 71 of which are only being applied to one question at the moment.

Some of these are obviously useful (e.g. [mice](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mice)) whereas [sound](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) and [ice](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice) are probably less relevant to a wider set of questions.

Should we at this stage already try and weed some of those out or should we wait until we got a bigger set of questions?

I can see pros and cons for both but at the moment I am more worried about bad tags becoming established than people not finding a tag they are looking for (so far, few people seem worried about starting a new tag).

Answer (score 2):

I think we need a bit of time in the public beta phase to see if some of these tags start to take off more. Right now, we're a fairly limited number of people asking questions and building a base of information for the roll out of the public beta and so I would be reluctant, myself, to trim that with having a bit more usage to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

It might be good to wait until the private beta ends. During the private beta everyone can add new tags as only 1 rep is needed. It might happen that tags are removed and immediately recreated afterwards, especially those that currently have more than one question tagged with it.

After we enter the private beta 150 rep are necessary to create new tags, so even users that receive the 100 rep association-bonus are not able to immediately create tags that are considered bad on our site.

For *some* tags it might be OK to remove them now, eg `ice` which I created. But it already happened to me that perfectly valid tags were removed. So if in doubt, please discuss the removal of a tag in a comment or ask a question here on meta.